# How can I make a 3 second countdown without using the time.sleep() function

Tags: python, time, computer-vision, sleep, countdown

I need a function to start a countdown from 3 to 0 for a rock, paper, scissors game that uses the webcam to determine the users choice.

I want the program to start the image capture, then begin the countdown and capture the users input once the countdown reaches 0. I want the image capture running in the background as soon as the program starts, and then the countdown to activate once the image capture is running because the image capture takes several seconds to start up.

The issue is time.sleep() stops the image capture from running in the background and therefore stops the program capturing the users input until the countdown is stopped, which means that the countdown would start and once it hit 0, it would then start up the image capture, which would take several seconds.

Currently, my countdown function counts up from zero, and also prints multiple iterations of the same number.

Code:

```
def countdown():

     countdown_time = 3
     start_time = time.time()

     while (time.time() - start_time) < countdown_time:
        print(round(time.time() - start_time))
        if (time.time() - start_time) >= countdown_time:
            break
```

Ideally it should just print:

```
3
2
1
```

But it prints something more like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
```

link to my GitHub repo (https://github.com/luketl98/ComputerVisionProject.git)

Comment: _I can't use the time.sleep() as that particular function won't start the program_ - huh?

Comment: To more explicitly state @wim's question: What do you mean by _"as that particular function won't start the program"_? You pause the execution of your code using `time.sleep`. It has nothing to do with starting the program. I'm willing to bet you tried something with `time.sleep` that was wrong, and decided that was the wrong tool to use (it's not).

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: Well, it would be if this was an `asyncio` program (where you want `await asyncio.sleep(...)`), but yes, it would be very weird if you *needed* a spin loop that waited for a second at a time.

Comment: The file that I want to run is a game that uses the cameras input, and I can't use the time.sleep() function because it will stop the script running, so it would stop taking an input from the camera -- Apologies for any lack of clarity

Comment: You keep making edits in the hope of attracting other answers? You will have to do a better job of explaining why you can’t use `pause`, because the answer below is the best thing you can do and the only thing anyone on here would recommend.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yeah I think you're right, very new to StackOverflow here, was just trying to keep the question short - Would I be better off deleting and reposting with a more full/descriptive explanation?

Comment: You can't delete, you've already gotten an answer. Considering you're *clarifying* your problem statement, I think it's OK to edit the post -- as long as you don't change the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

I think this what you are looking for:

```
from time import sleep

def countDown():
    for i in range(3, 0, -1):
        print(i)
        sleep(1)
        
countDown()
```

You are saying that you can't use the `time.sleep()` as that particular function won't start the program which is wrong. It works here just fine.

Comment: So I'm writing a program that lets you play rock, paper, scissors using the webcam to detect the users choice (using an image model I made with TeachableMachine). 
Currently the program starts, boots up for several seconds and begins capturing the users choice via the webcam. But I want it to start running the script, then count down from 3, determine the users choice at 0 seconds, stop the script(image capture) and give the result of the game. 

It's difficult to explain hence so I'll post a link to my GitHub repo (https://github.com/luketl98/ComputerVisionProject.git)